# Target Table is not updated

Tags: mysql

The target table is not updatable.

```
`DELIMITER $$

    ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `po` AS 
    SELECT
      `po_of_bom`.`Product_Name`        AS `Product_Name`,
      `po_of_bom`.`Component_Name`      AS `Component_Name`,
      `po_of_bom`.`Component_Barcode`   AS `Component_Barcode`,
      `po_of_bom`.`Manufacturer_Name`   AS `Manufacturer_Name`,
      `po_of_bom`.`PO No.`              AS `PO Number`,
      `po_of_bom`.`Order Status`        AS `Order Status`,
      `po_of_bom`.`QTY_of_parts_needed` AS `QTY_of_parts_needed`,
      `po_of_bom`.`SumOfPrice_IN_U$`    AS `SumOfPrice_IN_U$`,
      `qty_in_stock`.`QTY_In_Stock`     AS `QTY_In_Stock`
    FROM (`qty_in_stock`
       JOIN `po_of_bom`
         ON ((`qty_in_stock`.`Component_Barcode_ID` = `po_of_bom`.`Component_Barcode`)))$$

    DELIMITER ;`
```

Comment: whats the exact error message?

Comment: Record was not edited. The target table po of the update is not updatable.